# How do I prevent emacsclient --tty FILE from flashing the other frame's buffer before loading FILE

Tags: buffers, emacsclient, server

With `emacs -Q` if you `M-x server-start`, then open a buffer, then back in the terminal `emacsclient --tty SOMEOTHERFILE` a new frame will be created, but it will initially show the buffer shown in the original frame prior to displaying the file/buffer specified on the command line.

I know this is a visual nit, but it's distracting. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Either by showing the scratch buffer initially or loading straight in to the file specified at the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently not possible at the moment, this is just the way it works. It is possible to change this behavior, but it would require restructuring how server-process-filter works.

> Eli Zaretskii writes:
>
> The reason is simple: the way server.el
> is written, we first create the client frame, and only then show the
> file there.  So the frame is created with no file to visit, and Emacs
> always shows the last buffer in the new frame in those cases.

See http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2017-05/msg00502.html